# How can I load a remote file using file_get_contents()?

Tags: php, file-get-contents, file-put-contents

Scratching my head a bit now with this.
I am trying to get a file from a remote url. I can save contents from local files, but can't from remote.

This works:

```
file_put_contents(
    'file1.xml',
    file_get_contents('file2.xml')
);
```

This doesn't:

```
file_put_contents(
    'file1.xml',
    file_get_contents('http://www.domain.com/xmlapi/search.aspx?query=places&lid=38')
);
```

Oddly enough my other scripts worked ok at first try but none will access the remote url now.
I have recently started to host my new php files on Heart Internet. I have similar scripts on other servers which give no problems at all.

This is the error I get:

> Warning: file_get_contents() [function.file-get-contents]: php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known in /home/sites/mydomain/myfile.php on line 5`
>
> Warning: file_get_contents(http://www.domain.com/xmlapi/search.aspx?query=places&lid=38) [function.file-get-contents]: failed to open stream: php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known in /home/sites/mydomain/public_html/myfile.php on line 5`

`allow_url_fopen` is set to `On`

Different domains

Comment: Any error messages? Add `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` at the top of your script.

Comment: Are both the files on the same domain? Asking coz' I have experienced that some web hosting provider block the call (from firewall) made to the outside domains....

Comment: is the http wrapper allowed for such connections?

Comment: You might have to set "allow_url_fopen = On" in php.ini

Comment: php.ini setting is allow_url_fopen = On

Comment: That means `domain.com` cannot be resolved to an IP address.

Comment: Has something changed at my service provider end then ? The scripts did fetch the files for a day or two when I first constructed 3 or 4 pages. The retrieved data is still in my sql database tables.

Answer (score 5):

check the php settings...

it may be due to security issue... "allow_url_fopen = On"

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php

Answer (score 1):

> Warning: file_get_contents() [function.file-get-contents]: php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known in /home/sites/mydomain/myfile.php on line 5`

This would suggest you are either using an incorrect url, or DNS is not correctly set up on your server.